# Delete drawn vectors from map in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a map where I want to draw features as well as displaying their attributes. This I have done without problems.

My problem is that I want the layers to be deleted from the map when pressing the "delete"-button with the help of an "on-click" function. I have managed to get the attributes that are written when a layer is drawn to disappear by the on-click function. However, no matter what I do, the drawn layers are still visible.

I have been trying to solve this for two days straight and have tried everything on this forum (where `layer.getSource().clear()` seems to be the most advised method), but form me it doesn't work.

I have provided my whole script (somewhat edited to make function when posting this question).

```
<title>DeleteData</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ol.js"></script>                
        <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        function init () {

        // Initial view 
                var viewInit = new ol.View({
                    center: ol.proj.transform([13.1920, 55.71], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    zoom: 12,
                    minZoom: 10,
                    maxZoom: 20,
                    });

        // the source for Bing Map

        var bingMapsAerial = new ol.layer.Tile({
        preload: Infinity,
        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
          key: 'AqbNasIax2PdLZ6zeE15xRaZgngM4EiqhMGIBKNWKj7TrAAjPeHpZ4uE7k4nW9Qr',
          imagerySet: 'Aerial',
        })

        // Create Source for Drawing features
        var Drawsource = new ol.source.Vector();       

        // Create Layer for Drawing Features
        var DrawFeature = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: Drawsource, style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#ff3333',
                    width: 4
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 4,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#ffcc33'

                    })
                })
            })

        // The map with our custom interactions, controls and overlays
        var map = new ol.Map({
          layers:  [bingMapsAerial,DrawFeature ],
          view: 'EPSG:3857',
          controls: ol.control.defaults({attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false})
                }).extend([

                    // Control for displaying Mouse Position
                    new ol.control.MousePosition({
                    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
                    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
                    target: document.getElementById('PositionOfMouse'),
                    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'


                    // Control for displaying the Scale-line
                    new ol.control.ScaleLine({
                    target: document.getElementById('scale-line'),

          target: 'map',
          view: viewInit


        // make draw global so it can later be removed
        var draw;

        // creat a select to choose geometry type
        var typeSelect = document.getElementById('geom_type');
        // rebuild interaction when changed
        typeSelect.onchange = function (e) {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            addInteraction();
        };

         // create a select to choose a data type to save in
        dataTypeSelect = document.getElementById('data_type');
        // clear map and rebuild interaction when changed
        dataTypeSelect.onchange = function (e) {
            clearMap();
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            addInteraction();
        };

        // add draw interaction
        function addInteraction() {
            var geom_type = typeSelect.value;
            if (geom_type !== 'None') {
                draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                    source: Drawsource,
                    type:(geom_type)

                });

                draw.on('drawend', function (evt1) {
                   saveData();
                });

                map.addInteraction(draw);
            }
        }

        function saveData() {
            var allFeatures = Drawsource.getFeatures(),
                format = new ol.format[dataTypeSelect.value](),
                data;'GeoJSON'
            try {
                data = format.writeFeatures(allFeatures);
            } catch (e) {
                document.getElementById('data').value = e.name + ": " + e.message;
                return;
            }
            if (geom_type.value !== 'None') {
                document.getElementById('datatext').value = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
            } 
        }

        // clears the map and the output of the data
         function yourFunction(){
     document.getElementById('datatext').value = "";

    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
            <div id="PositionOfMouse"></div>
            <div id="scale-line" class="scale-line"></div>       
            <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
              <select id="geom_type">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Point">Point</option>
                <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
                <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
              </select>

        <label>Data type</label>
        <select id="data_type">
            <option value="GeoJSON" selected>GeoJSON</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick="yourFunction();">delete</button>
    </div>
        <div id="nodelist"></div>

    <div id="info"></div>
     <div><textarea id="datatext"></textarea></div>
    </html>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Hi, Im new to this forum.. I have edited the post with my question now. Is it understandable?

Comment: `Drawsource.clear();` should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried to experiment with that. I have put it in the "function yourFunction" that activates when the delete button is pushed. However, the layers are still on the map (in comparison with the datatext.value that is erased by an " "-string. Have you got any clue how i should implement it more specifically?